# SCSS/SASS Compass Folder Terminal Command

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I see that to use Compass' opacity feature in an SCSS file you must

```
@import "compass/css3/opacity";
```

However, I cannot install the Compass folder as required above to the project directory using

```
compass install
```

(Compass has already been installed in ruby 'gem install compass')

I have tried

```
compass create
```

But this does not create the compass directory that I need for the @import to work.

How can I install the compass folder to a directory so that the import can work?

Comment: Keep in mind that Compass comes with extensions (which is where `/compass/css3/opacity` lives).

Comment: @cimmanon and how is it supposed to be used?  if you are going to mark this as a duplicate I would appreciated that you link where the post is..

Comment: The link to the answer above my post does not answer my question at all.  Please remove the duplicate post mark.

Comment: I have found the compass executable in /usr/bin/ but I do not see any compass folder.

Comment: You shouldn't *have* a compass directory, that's what the linked question explains.  The file you're trying to import is part of a Compass extension, one that is included by default.  You're just supposed to follow the installation instructions (which it appears as though you've done), then compile it.  Did you try compiling it via `compass watch` or `compass compile`?

Comment: I really don't want to have compass compile it separately.  I am using bourbon and it has a directory with the folders making it an easy job to simply compile scss and have the imports traversed by the scss compiler for linking.  I don't want an scss compile and then a compass compile.  What can I do?

Comment: I may be missing something about what the compass compiler may need todo to need itself... I would think that all the compass code is, is scss mixins and such.  So I dont see a need for it to be using its own compiler.  For now I just made my own mixin for opacity and placed it an include file - no need for an extra compilation - simple.

Comment: If you're using Compass, you only use the `compass` command.  Compass is *not* just a collection of mixins, it includes a number of Ruby functions as well.  Also, you never mentioned you were using Bourbon.  https://github.com/jedfoster/bourbon-compass

Comment: Thanks for that link but I cannot rely on someone to repackage bourbon with every update, nor should they be expected to.  It seems as if I won't be using compass for now.  Thanks for the clarification.